# Mojo::DOM manipulation

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I would like to remove second `<p>` node and its content from:

```
 <div>
   <p>1<div>D</div></p>

   <p>2</p>
 </div>
```

Checked [children](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#children) method, but it also returns all descending nodes, while I would like to get first level `<p>` nodes.

```
perl -Mojo -E'
say for @{ x("
    <div>
    <p>1<div>D</div></p>

    <p>2</p>
    </div>
  ")->at("div")->children }
'
```

output

```
<p>1</p>
<div>D</div>
<p>2</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
perl -Mojo -E'
say for @{ x("
    <div>
    <p>1<div>D</div></p>

    <p>2</p>
    </div>
  ")->find("div > p")}
'
```

output

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
```

But i'm unsure that this is what do you want..

Comment: Or `->at('div')->children('p')`

Comment: @Borodin yes, this is even better, because the my `find` will find the deeper nested `p`s too.

Comment: That's what I thought. But the OP doesn't want to tell us anything useful about their problem so it's hard to tell what is required. I'd like to know if they're *really* trying to process malformed HTML or something else. It's a poor question really.

Answer (score 2):

> Checked `children` method, but it also returns all descending nodes

The example you show tries to parse invalid HTML, which has an illegal `<div>` element inside a `<p>` paragraph. The parser solves this by moving the closing `</p>` to before the opening `<div>`, which is pretty much what a real browser would do. So the call to `children` is correctly finding all three children of the top-level `<div>`, not all descendants as you surmised

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Mojo::DOM;

say Mojo::DOM->new(<<END)->at('div');
<div>
  <p>1<div>D</div></p>

  <p>2</p>
</div>
END
```

#### output

```
<div>
  <p>1</p><div>D</div>

  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

But you don't need it to remove the first child `<p>` element of a `<body>` element. That would look like this

```
$dom->at('body > p')->remove
```

To remove the *second* `<p>` child of a `<div>` would look like this

```
$dom->find('div > p')->[1]->remove
```

but the `<div>` element really needs a better specification